# I am trying to write select using class, but it doesnot work

Tags: php

I want to call 2 column from DB newsId and title and then print it.

My code looks like this:

```
class edit
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }


    public function news($neswID, $title)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT newsID, title FROM `news`");

        $result = $sql->execute(array($newsID, $title));

        while ($sql->fetch($result)) {
            print $neswID . '<br>' . $title;
        }

    }
}
```

and I call this class like this:

```
include_once "test.php";
$object= new edit();
$object->news($newsID, $title);
```

I am really new, thank you for help.

Comment: What is the condition to get newsId and title. As you are passing to your function

Comment: You spelt `$neswID` wrong in `public function news()`. It should be `$newsID`.

Comment: What type of DB-connection does the `Connection`-class establish? I hope you're using PDO

Comment: I changed $newsID, but again it does not work.

Comment: Yes i use PDo, I am just studying it....

Answer (score 0):

change you code to

```
$sql->execute();

while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  print $row['newsId'] .'<br>'. $row['title'] .'<br>';
}
```

prepare() return a [PDOStatement][1]
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop should be like this, as your column name are `newsID` and `title`

```
$sql->execute(); 
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo $row['newsID'].'==='.$row['title'];
}
```

Comment: Wow , ID start printing but title still no. thank you

Comment: what is column name for title in your db table?

Comment: title is the name of column.